# React native: How to individually control each onpress() from map() generated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.
I'm rendering 3 dropdowns in a row, multiple times according to the no of elements in an array.
So if the array has 3 elements, there will be 3 rows of 3 dropdowns.
But when invoke an onpress from a single dropdown it affects corresponding elements all 3 rows.
How can i individually control each row.?
Lot of solutions say use **bind** but the way i tried did not affect anything.
[click to see the rendered layout looks for 3 elements in the arrray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9k7U.jpg)

```
render_center_selection(){

      return(
        this.props.selecteddays_array.map((a, i) => {
          return(
           <View key={i} style={{ height:40, borderBottomWidth:2, borderBottomColor: '#ededed' }}>{
                      <View  style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <ModalDropdown 
                            style={styles.selection}
                            defaultValue='Venue'
                            textStyle={{width:200,fontSize:20,textAlign:'center',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownstyle}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{width:350,fontSize:20,textAlign:'center',backgroundColor: '#FDD60B',}}
                            options={this.state.venue_name_array}
                            onSelect={(index,value)=>{this.onVenueSelect(index,value)}}/>
                        <ModalDropdown 
                            ref="modal_dayselect"
                            style={styles.dayselection}
                            defaultValue='Day'
                            textStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.daydropdownstyle}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',backgroundColor: '#FDD60B',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            options={this.state.day_array}
                            onSelect={(index,value)=>{this.onDaySelect(index,value)}}/>
                        <ModalDropdown 
                            ref="modal_hrsselect"
                            style={styles.dayselection}
                            defaultValue='HRS'
                            textStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.daydropdownstyle}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',backgroundColor: '#FDD60B',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            options={this.state.hrs_array}
                            onSelect={(index,value)=>{this.setState({selected_hr:value})}}/>
                        {(this.state.editstatus)
                          ?<Text>Edit</Text>
                          :<Text></Text>
                        }
                      </View>
                  }</View>)                          
        }) 
      );
  }
```

Comment: You have single component to render these elements ? Have you checked you are calling `setState` on same component.

Comment: Sorry i did't get what u meant. I'm new to this. Can u explain it more please

Comment: Are you using any component to render this view. As in react we have component for rendering UI elements. So the `setState` method you are calling belongs to some component. If the elements you are rendering are inside a single component. Then the changes will be reflected throughout.

Comment: There's no onPress method in your code. Is it onSelect?

Comment: Shouldn't you be rendering just one `ModalDropdown ` since it's inside `.map()`?

Comment: Also, can you highlight where `.map(""a"", i) =>` is? I can not seem to find it

Comment: @Prabodh M : Yes the elements rendered are inside a single component class

Comment: @Raymond the "a" is a dummy array that contains the each day of week. so it will be rendered that many times

Comment: The `ModalDropdown` will be rendered 7 times based on the week? or do you mean that each `ModalDropdown` will have the that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass a unique key to the onSelect method then you will be able to individually control each row. In the below example, you can see there are two arrays and to get the data of inner array, I have to pass the index of outer array as well as the index of inner array. This will also make it unique.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3]
var arr2 = ['a','b','c']


function looper(data1,data2){
  data1.map((item1,index1) => {
   data2.map((item2,index2) =>console.log("item1: " + item1 + " " + index1 + " item2: " + item2 + " " + index2));
  })
}
looper(arr2,arr1);
```

Comment: thanks I solved it another roundabout way, BUT your answer gave me the idea. I tried our way but it did't work